# How to use the value of one variable in the name of another in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, variables

I am trying to make a simple keygen app (hoping to evolve it later) and am running into a problem with naming my variables:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim keylength As Double = TrackBar1.Value
    Dim baseloop As Double = 1
    Dim charpos As Double = 1
    Do While baseloop < keylength
        Randomize()
        Dim name As String = "num" & charpos
        Dim (name) As Integer = CInt(Int((62 * Rnd()) + 1))
        'I would like to name this variable the current value of the variable "name".
        baseloop = baseloop + 1
        charpos = charpos + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

The end result should be random doubles (as many as TrackBar1.Value) containing random doubles from 1-62 and named num1, num2, num3, etc.... Then I can replace all the 1s with a, 2 with b, etc etc....

Thanks for your help

Comment: It sounds like what you need is an array to store your 62 values.

Comment: OK but I don't know how long the final string is going to be... I need to be able to create infinite values of numX.... I don't need help reassigning the values, I need help in USING the value of name in the naming of the next variable. That is the only spot where I need help...    Thanks anyway for your time

Comment: You can't do what your asking- plan and simple. You can make a dictionary object with the key as a string built from the loop variables then give the value a value. It's a key/value pair. Or you need something else, but without know what your intent is its hard to say.

Comment: For now, I just want to make a key generator. I want to make a TrackBar where the user can select the length, then it will use that length (say X) and will create X variables with a random value 1-62 named num1, num2, etc.... 62 because 26 lowercase letters, 26 uppercase letters, and 10 numbers. Making these replacements would make me a randomized key.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, what you claim to want to do is not possible.  You can't declare an arbitrary number of variables at run time because variables are declared at design time.  If you want to store an arbitrary number of values then you declare one variable and assign to that variable an array or collection of some sort.  An array can be created with any size at run time and collections can grow to an arbitrary size at run time.  Basically, what you're trying to do is outright wrong.

If you want an arbitrary number of `Double` values then create an array with a sized based on a user-defined value and then simply loop to populate it, e.g.

```
Dim values(userDefinedValue - 1) As Double

For i = 0 To values.GetUpperBound(0)
    '...
Next
```

You then access the values by index.  The first value is at index 0, the second at index 1, ..., the last at index `GetUpperBound(0)`.

Comment: Thanks, I found a different way to do what I wanted: using a finalkey variable and tacking on the generated characters one at a time (using the random function) with the command `finalkey = finalkey & xxx` Thanks for your help though, I appreciate it and I will look into this solution too.